# Generating ONVIF digest - does not compute correct value

Tags: digest-authentication, onvif

I am trying to crete digest for ONVIF authentification.
For nonce, date and password, I am using example values from [Generating an ONVIF authentication digest using Crypto++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093175/generating-an-onvif-authentication-digest-using-crypto).

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Formula for digest is:

```
Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )
```

This are initial values:

```
nonce = LKqI6G/AikKCQrN0zqZFlg==
date = 2010-09-16T07:50:45Z
password = userpassword
```

Decoding nonce is done with his command:

```
echo -n "LKqI6G/AikKCQrN0zqZFlg==" | base64 -d
Result is: ,���o��B�B�tΦE�
```

Concatenating decoded nonce, date and password I got:

```
,���o��B�B�tΦE�2010-09-16T07:50:45Zuserpassword
```

Hash is calculated with this command:

```
echo -n ",���o��B�B�tΦE�2010-09-16T07:50:45Zuserpassword" | sha1sum
Result: c6c63f09a5f074e8a4d21ec8a264013425476041
```

Finaly, encoding is done with this command:

```
echo - n "c6c63f09a5f074e8a4d21ec8a264013425476041" | base64
Result is: LSBuIGM2YzYzZjA5YTVmMDc0ZThhNGQyMWVjOGEyNjQwMTM0MjU0NzYwNDEK
```

But, it is expected:

```
tuOSpGlFlIXsozq4HFNeeGeFLEI=
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346735/795910 . It should help you.